# What is the best way to occasionally play a sound?

Tags: audio

I have a speaker (Bose SoundLink Mini) connected to my MacBook Pro, and it switches off after periods of non-use. This means that it will shut off even while I am at the computer, if a sound hasn't been played in awhile. What is the most sensible way to have a very quiet (ideally inaudible) sound played every fifteen minutes? I have a little familiarity with AppleScript and am happy to learn more; I don't yet know anything about other scripting methods.

Comment: Create an applescript or perhaps try chron ? Two possibilities you can check.

Comment: `/usr/bin/afplay` might help. What's your level of expertise regarding shell scripts, AppleScript, launchd/cron?

Comment: Thanks! My level of expertise is minimal with AppleScript, and none with shell scripts and cron. (On the other hand, I like to learn.)

Comment: Please add your own solutions as one answer below, this makes it easier to find them in the future.

Comment: Done (I think)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific speaker, it turns out there is [an easier answer](https://www.bose.com/en_us/support/article/auto-off-setting-soundlink-mini-ii.html): just press and hold the bluetooth and + buttons until it verifies that auto-off has been disabled. Still, thank you all for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a launch agent which repeatedly says something (or plays a sound) and load it:

1. Create a plist with nano in Terminal:

   ```
   nano ~/Library/LaunchAgent/usr.home.bose.wakeup.plist
   ```
2. Copy the following lines and paste it into the Terminal window:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>Disabled</key>
       <false/>
       <key>Label</key>
       <string>usr.home.bose.wakeup</string>
       <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
           <string>/usr/bin/say</string>
           <string>wake</string>
           <string>up</string>
           <string>you</string>
           <string>lazy</string>
           <string>Bose</string>
           <string>SoundLink</string>
           <string>Mini</string>
       </array>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
       <true/>
       <key>StartInterval</key>
       <integer>887</integer>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
3. Save the file with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and exit nano with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>
4. Load the plist with:

   ```
   launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgent/usr.home.bose.wakeup.plist
   ```

You can use other voices by adding the option `-v $VOICE`. To get the list of all available voices enter `say -v ?` in Terminal.

Example:

```
...
<array>
    <string>/usr/bin/say</string>
    <string>-v</string>
    <string>Agnes</string>
    <string>wake</string>
...
```

The downside of `say`: you can't set a sound level!

Therefore an alternative launch agent with `afplay` instead (you can set the sound level with the -v option):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>usr.home.bose.wakeup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/afplay</string>
        <string>-v</string>
        <string>0.05</string>
        <string>/System/Library/Sounds/Submarine.aiff</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>887</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: So the entire `say` part of your answer is not an answer to the question? Should it be two  separate answers, or re-ordered so the useful answer is more prominent?

Comment: @theonlygusti  The `say` part answers the question **"What is the best way to occasionally play a sound?"** but doesn't meet one contraint: *to [be] very quiet (ideally inaudible)*. I rather wanted to show how to use a launch agent to repeatedly play a sound.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm sure I could record something more quiet, or perhaps even a recording of silence would work.